# Seeking historical traffic data matching OpenStreetMap dataset?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, traffic, openstreetmap

I'm using San Francisco dataset offered by OpenStreetMap and I'm trying to get the optimal path using the `pgr-astar` function of PostgreSQL.

I want to find the historical traffic data of San Francisco roads (roads congestion with time slots), that corresponds to the format of the dataset generated by the map so I can calculate the optimal path based on the historical traffic information of each road segment.

Where can I get this data?

This is the dataset of San Francisco, where a road is divided into many segments.

[image]

I found many sites that offer the traffic information but it doesn't match my dataset ( without accurate information of the road segment).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to process the data yourself. This type of data isn’t collected against osm because there is no guarantee of consistency

Comment: How does osm provide "guarantee of consistency"?